# How to understand the error "subscipts out of bound", when indexing a column matrix with a matrix

Tags: r, matrix, vectorization, subscript

Consider the following code example:

The objective is to replace the indices in mymatrix with the corresponding values in mypoints.

```
# example 1--------------------------------------------- 
mymatrix <- c(3,4,1,2, 2,1,4,3, 4,3,2,1)
dim(mymatrix) <- c(4,3)
mypoints <- matrix(c(10, 20, 30, 40), nrow(mymatrix), 1)
# loop
mysummary <- mypoints[mymatrix[,1]]
for (i in 2:ncol(mymatrix) ) {
  mysummary <- cbind(mysummary, mypoints[mymatrix[,i]])
}
# ------------------------------------------------------
```

The result is:

```
     mysummary      
[1,]        30 20 40
[2,]        40 10 30
[3,]        10 40 20
[4,]        20 30 10
```

The loop can be replaced in a more concise way:

```
> mysummary      <- mypoints[mymatrix]
> dim(mysummary) <- dim(mymatrix)
```

The result:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   30   20   40
[2,]   40   10   30
[3,]   10   40   20
[4,]   20   30   10
```

However, this does not work in following smaller example:

```
# example 3---------------------------------------------
> mymatrix <- c(2,1, 2,1)
> dim(mymatrix) <- c(2,2)
> mypoints <- matrix(c(10, 20), nrow(mymatrix), 1)
> mysummary      <- mypoints[mymatrix]
Error in mypoints[mymatrix] : subscript out of bounds
```

I have no idea which subscript is out of bounds and in which array. And how to prevent this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the indexing matrix `mymatrix` has two columns, then R assumes that you want to use the first column as the row index and the second as the column index.  So it fails as the first row of `mymatrix` in your second example is `2,2`, which is out of bounds in `mypoints`.

In your first example, `mymatrix` has more than 2 columns, so R treats it as a vector, which is the only way that makes sense in the circumstances.

Comment: In example 3, `mysummary <- mypoints[c(mymatrix)]` solves the problem, as suggested by Andrew. Or as.vector() instead of c().

Answer (score 0):

`mypoints` is a degenerate matrix - it's basically a "blown-up" (where a singular second dimension is added) vector. So when you try to access the index 2 in the second dimension, it fails as the second dimension has only index 1. A small modification works:

```
mymatrix <- c(2,1, 2,1)
dim(mymatrix) <- c(2,2)
mypoints <- matrix(c(10, 20), nrow(mymatrix), 2)
mysummary <- mypoints[mymatrix]
```

Comment: But why does this argument not also apply to Example 1?

Comment: When you index (subset) into a matrix (a 2 by 2 array) with a `[,i]` notation, you are extracting the `i`th column as a vector (1-D object). Then you are indexing into a 4 by 1 object (`mypoints`) with a vector (and none of the values of the vector exceed 4) - so I don't see why the same problem would arise as in Example 3, where you are trying to access the `[2,2]` element of a 4 by 1 object (which is not possible).